# NACK Error message is not valid?

Tags: hl7, hapi

I have an issue about the NACK message generated by HAPI,

I'm generating the NACK message as follows;

```
 Message msg= hl7Msg.generateACK(HL7Constants.HL7_MSA_ERROR_FIELD_VALUE, 
                    new HL7Exception(errorMsg));
```

This returns; following message;

```
MSH|^~\&|||||20130604165513.576+0100||ACK|108|P|2.5 
MSA|AE|HL7Gtw01361605B49500 
ERR|^^^207&ERROR&hl70357&&errmsg
```

If you notice the ERR segment, it doesn't have required info;

Is the above message valid?

I suspect it has to be like this;

```
MSH|^~\&|||||20130604165513.576+0100||ACK|108|P|2.5 
MSA|AE|HL7Gtw01361605B49500 
ERR|||207|E|^errmsg
```

Why do i get such invalid message? Am i doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Can you give me the complete code you have written?

Comment: Sid,  This is the line i did to generate NACK message; hl7Msg.generateACK('AE',new HL7Exception(errorMsg));  this is the API link, i used to generate ack http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/apidocs/src-html/ca/uhn/hl7v2/model/Message.html#line.170

Comment: @Sid please refer this question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957792/why-nack-message-misses-to-create-the-fields-3-4-and-5-in-hapi

Comment: @Sid any idea, why this happens?

Comment: At present i cant say anything, until I reproduce the error on my system.

Comment: @Sid i got help from hapi mailing list..the issue is the version i used..

Answer (score 0):

Ans from hapi mailing list;

If possible, you should upgrade to most recent version (2.1). This version makes the distinction between ERR segments as of version 2.5 (where ERR-2 and ERR-3 is populated) and before version 2.5 (where ERR-1 is used) when generateACK is called with an Exception.

Anyway, you can use util classes like Terser to modify fields of the ERR segment in the ACK message as you wish. In your case you would probably have to copy values from ERR-1 to ERR-3

```
    Segment err = (Segment)msg.get("ERR");
    Terser.set(err, 3, 0, 1, 1, Terser.get(err, 1, 0, 4, 1));
    Terser.set(err, 3, 0, 2, 1, Terser.get(err, 1, 0, 4, 2));
    Terser.set(err, 3, 0, 3, 1, Terser.get(err, 1, 0, 4, 3));
    Terser.set(err, 3, 0, 9, 1, Terser.get(err, 1, 0, 4, 5));
    Terser.set(err, 4, 0, 1, 1, "E");
```

and optionally remove the values in ERR-1 afterwards:

Terser.set(err, 1, 0, 4, 1, "");