# Why NACK message misses to create the Fields 3,4 and 5 in Hapi

Tags: hl7, hapi

The NACK message generated by HAPI missed to add 3, 4, 5 fields

I'm generating the NACK message as follows;

Message msg= hl7Msg.generateACK(HL7Constants.HL7_MSA_ERROR_FIELD_VALUE, 
                    new HL7Exception(errorMsg));

This returns; following message;

```
MSH|^~\&|||||20130604165513.576+0100||ACK|108|P|2.5 
MSA|AE|HL7Gtw01361605B49500 
ERR|^^^207&ERROR&hl70357&&errmsg
```

If you notice the ERR segment, it doesn't have 3,4,5 fields

Any idea why hapi missed to add field 3,4 and 5?
I checked with Hapi testpanel, above two messages are valid but in very first NACK message, i dont get field 3,4,5..
I would like to get with fields..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because hapi 1,2 version doesn't make any distinction in the error filed. After upgrading to 2.1 version im getting the error segments.

Comment: Are you upgrading the HAPI Version within WSO2?

Comment: in the ESB 4.7.0 version it is upgraded to 2.1 version