# HL7 How to send a NACK message with hapifhir

Tags: java, hl7-fhir, hl7-v2

I am creating an HL7 interface. When the messages that are recieved are correct, i reply to HIS with a ACK message like this:

```
msg.generateACK();
```

How do i send a NACK message, indicating that the message was recieved but it's content was not correct? I am using ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.Message.

Comment: Are you using HAPI v2 or HAPI fhir?  They're different products.  It looks like you're just using v2...

Answer (score 0):

To generate a NACK, you need to

```
msg.generateACK(theAcknowlegementCode,theException);
```

**Parameters:**

1. theAcknowlegementCode - If null, defaults to AcknowledgmentCode.AA.
   To generate a typical NAK, use AcknowledgmentCode.AE
2. theException - The exceptions used to populate the ERR segment (if any)

See https://hapifhir.github.io/hapi-hl7v2/base/apidocs/index.html for more details

Also [Why NACK message misses to create the Fields 3,4 and 5 in Hapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957792/why-nack-message-misses-to-create-the-fields-3-4-and-5-in-hapi) has an example